# Как выполнить инстанцирование объекта в generic-типе?

Tags: c#

Создаю свой generic-абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractGeneric<T> where T : MyClass
{
    protected T instance;

    public T MyProp
    {
        get
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = new T(); //компилятор не позволяет создавать объект таким образом
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Как правильно инстанциировать объект в таком случае?

Comment: есть `constraint` _new_

Comment: @Grundy, а если нужно передать параметры в конструктор?

Comment: @klutch1991 Через Activator.CreateInstance()

Comment: Вы случайно не `Lazy<T>` пытаетесь сделать? Там это реализовано через конструктор с параметром `Func<T> valueFactory`.

Comment: [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для указания, что параметр `T` должен иметь конструктор по умолчанию можно использовать ограничение [`new()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Тогда код уже не будет ругаться на `new T()`

Так же в .net присутствует возможность создания объектов с помощью класса [Activator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Например, [Activator.CreateInstance(Type type,  params object[] args)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
instanse = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T),parameters);
```

Comment: Предупреждаю: оба этих способа - страшно медленные.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, по сравнению с чем?

Comment: По сравнению с обычным созданием объекта через конструктор, без генериков.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, есть какие-то замеры, статьи?

Comment: Тот факт, что Reflection тормозит, общеизвестен.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже сказал Grundy в своём ответе, для того, чтобы компилятор позволил `instance = new T();`, нужно добавить к ограничениям на тип `T` наличие `new()` (конструктор без параметров).

Если нужно передавать в конструктор параметры, то можно добавить защищённый делегат `Func<T> createInstance`, который будет использоваться для создания экземпляра:

```
//вместо MyClass я использовал ISerializable, просто чтобы пример был рабочим
public abstract class MyAbstractGeneric<T> where T : ISerializable, new()
{
    protected Func<T> createInstance = null;
    protected T instance;

    public T MyProp
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                //используем делегат, если он задан, иначе - конструктор по-умолчанию
                instance = createInstance == null ? new T() : createInstance();

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

И потом, при наследовании, задавать его, например, в конструкторе (либо передавать в конструктор параметром, как это сделано в `Lazy<T>`):

```
public class MyStringBuilder : MyAbstractGeneric<StringBuilder>
{
    public MyStringBuilder()
    {
        createInstance = null;
    }
    public MyStringBuilder(Func<StringBuilder> createInstance)
    {
        this.createInstance = createInstance;
    }
}
```

И далее:

```
var m = new MyStringBuilder();
var sb = m.MyProp; // -> {}
var m2 = new MyStringBuilder(() => { return new StringBuilder("abc"); });
var sb2 = m2.MyProp; // -> {abc}
```

Comment: Зря вы `new()` и создание через функцию поставили рядом, как альтернативы. Эти два способа отличаются по скорости в несколько раз.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, какие альтернативы? Как вы это видите? Присвоить делегату конструктор напрямую нельзя.

Comment: Через замыкание - можно. Можно даже создать его динамически через `Expresision`, *если предполагается многократный вызов*